# SQL инъекции joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, php, sql, взлом

Собственно интересуют базовые, или уязвимости часто встречающихся компонентов. Цель самая благородная, и почти не преступная(в рамках того, что это все же взлом), надо получить доступ к сайту владельца, который утратил пароль. Либо хотя бы ссылки на хорошие ресурсы по данному вопросу.

Comment: А почему бы вам самому не скачать последнюю версию и не изучить код?

Comment: Время очень мало. И последнюю мне ни к чему, потому, что знаю, что сайтик на 1.5 крутится. Собственно дело в том, что пароль не совсем утрачен, а не был передан по договору(не смотря, что этот пункт прописан очень явно), а фирма изготовляющая сайт испарилась, на звонки никто не отвечает и последнее обновление контента сайта было год назад . А хостинг в своей манере требует разрешение исполнителя.

Comment: айяйяй, какая занимательная история! и как благородно - утраченный пароль надо вернуть! надо помочь человеку! 

а в бд прописать заново не пробовали? или у вас и к бд нет доступа? хм, обратитесь к панели управления хостингом, и смените пароль к бд. 

что? нет доступа к панели управления хостингом?? 
обратитесь к хостинг провайдеру, предоставьте ему сканы документов, удостоверяющих Вашу личность, как владельца аккаунта, и они восстановят Ваш пароль.

Comment: Т.е. все пароли хостинга (базы,фтп) отсутствуют? Или только к админке джумлы?

Comment: Я не буду тут распылятся и оправдываться - не верить ваше право. Вся информация у исполнителя, телефон гендира фирмы молчит, в договоре интеллектуальная собственность принадлежит заказчику, а по факту аккаунт приписан на исполнителя, коды доступа и пароли к базам, фтп, админке и пр. ПЕРЕДАНЫ НЕ БЫЛИ. И если у меня был бы контроль над базой -я бы задавал бы этот вопрос!?

Comment: Платили за хостинг Вы? И вообще, разговаривали с провайдером?

Comment: Нет не я. Да разговаривал и он сказал предоставить ЕГРЮЛ(фирма не существует) и письменное согласие исполнителя ни первый ни второй пункт я выполнить не могу, а тем более оба.

Comment: Я не понимаю, если есть владелец ака от хостинга - никаких проблем нет, если владельца нет - значит ак не его, либо он вас обманывает, либо вы нас. В первом случае взлом сайта вам ничего не даст, доступ к панели вы не получите, зачем тогда ломать сайт?
А мне то скан зачем? дайте его хостинг провайдеру, и все проблемы решатся, как я уже сказал - взлом сайта ничего не даст, и тот, кто его делал в свободное время зайдет в панель управления хостингом и нету сайта.

Comment: Судя по всему, тут скорее юридический вопрос. Есть правда и положительный момент: если ничего не выйдет, то сделай им новый сайт и получи соответствующее вознаграждение. Кстати, а современный ЕГРЮЛ смотрели?

Comment: >А хэш пароля не дешифровать?

а посмотреть как joomla создает хэш можно? а сделать хэш из, например, **111** можно? все полегче будет, чем искать уязвимость.
Мое мнение - ситуация не совсем такая, как вы описываете, ибо я не вижу логики во взломе сайта, не имея доступов к панели (бд ftp и пр).

Comment: в md5 хеширует) Дешифруйте)

Comment: >в md5 хеширует) Дешифруйте)

да нафиг, создаешь хэш 111, если и правда соли нет, и все дела.
а если есть соль - посмотреть откуда он ее берет, и создать аналогичную ситуацию.. вобщем, бред это все. все равно, что пытаться найти способ вломиться в якобы свою квартиру, из которой формальный хозяин при первой же возможноси выпрет, еще и засудит.

Comment: соль есть!

Comment: Нет в джумле соли для хэшей пароля. Одна из фишек восстановления пароля - прямой запрос *`update jos_users set ... password=MD5('12345') ...`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://сайт.ru/index.php?option=com_user&view=reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри тут сплойты

> http://www.exploit-db.com/
>
> http://1337day.com/

плюс ко всему google с множеством информации